# How can I get specific type in `or` operator definition?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

For example I have type like this blow:

```
type ActionResource = {
    type: "QUERY";
    payload: IListPayload;
} | {
    type: "GET";
    payload: {
        id: string;
    };
} | {
    type: "QUERY_NEXT";
} | {
    type: "SAVE";
    payload: {
        id: string;
        data: any;
    };
} | {
    type: "SEARCH_TEXT";
    payload: {
        ...;
    };
}
```

Now I would like to get specific type which has `type` properties = 'SAVE'
So I do like this

```
type GetActionResourceType<K extends ActionResource['type']> = ActionResource
type SaveType = GetActionResourceType<'SAVE'>
```

I hope it will return type of SaveType look like:

```
{
    type: "SAVE";
    payload: {
        id: string;
        data: any;
}
```

How can I make `GetActionResourceType` in my purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `Extract` (see in [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) at Predefined conditional types)conditional type to extract a type that extends a specific  type:

```
type GetActionResourceType<K extends ActionResource['type']> = Extract<ActionResource, { type: K }>
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Where you know Extract type?

Comment: @LeTom please mark as answered if it was what you were looking for